# Plans to move microsoft graph sitepage & webparts api from beta to v1.0?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm in need to use the microsoft [sitepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sitepage?view=graph-rest-beta) and [webparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webpart?view=graph-rest-beta) api in production, and there is no way but only use the beta version.

I have been experiencing 500 errors with no context when using the [webparts api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webpart?view=graph-rest-beta).

Are there any plans for moving [sitepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sitepage?view=graph-rest-beta) and [webparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webpart?view=graph-rest-beta) api to version 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=Microsoft%20Graph), the shipment from `beta` to `v1.0` is planned for **September 2023**.

Comment: Shipment seems to be still in development, they don't note any other date.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, @AbdullahAlhariri I suspect that not everything went according to the plan, because they postponed the rollout. Now the shipment to v1.0 is planned for **March 2024**. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=101166